# google sheet SUM a range by address of the range

Tags: google-sheets

I have the address of the beginning and end of a range stored in especial cells like below:

[image]

I want to  use SUM function on this range like this:

```
SUM('P&L'!C3:'P&L'!D3)
```

I tried the INDIRECT function but I face an error:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(F2 & ":" & F3))

Function INDIRECT parameter 1 value is ''P&L'!C3:'P&L'!D3'. It is not a valid cell/range reference.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the sample data below

#### P&L:

[image: sample]

You could just use `indirect` to both ranges since both will then return cell references, and then `sum` those references and combine into a single range using `:`.

#### Formula:

```
=sum(indirect(F2):indirect(F3))
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

These two formulas work. See [this google sheet for examples](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fWlUN629ZUWU3y5LLpmxqFMRwrrfVvN73O4GZi9k0Zs/edit#gid=1158991417).

```
=sum(INDIRECT("'P&L'!C3:D3",true))

=sum(INDIRECT(F2&":"&F3,true))

=sum(INDIRECT("'P&L'!"&'P&L'!F2&":"&'P&L'!F3,true))
```

Also, this will create a volatile formula, a better choice would be to use Index as a range.

Comment: it didnt work. I think the problem is the sheet name. this formula is in a sheet, other than P&L sheet.

Comment: I happened to test your formula, and it gives the same result as mine, so i don't think your formula is wrong. Something much be off in your cell or spreadsheet. It's not your formula...

Comment: I would guess your data types or cell values might be string or not what you think they are.

Comment: the sheet that I am using this SUM function is not named P&L. The P&L is another sheet.

Comment: I see where you might have issue. Try this formula. I'll add it to the answer: `=sum(INDIRECT("'P&L'!"&'P&L'!F2&":"&'P&L'!F3,true))`

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following

In your cells use `P&L!C3` and `P&L!D3`

Your formula would be:

`=SUM(INDIRECT(A4),INDIRECT(A5))`

where `A4` and `A5` are your cells

[image]

Comment: That's essentially this formula but using two helper cells.... `=sum(INDIRECT("'P&L'!"&'P&L'!F2&":"&'P&L'!F3,true))`

Comment: I think I misread the question. I guess you need to sum the whole range. My formula will sum just the 2 cells. I believe the answer provided by NaziA is what you need.